# Django unitest - test image download

Tags: django, beautifulsoup, django-testing, django-tests

Hi have the follow code in for my Django test case, and the test case is failing because the c.get() is hitting a 404. So I'm getting this error. If I go to http://localost//static/recaptcha/47.jpg when I *python manage.py runserver 80*, and I can see my image fine there.

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
..>>>img_url: /static/recaptcha/47.jpg
F...
======================================================================
FAIL: test_signup_get (fastmojo.tests.test_account.FastMojoSignUpTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\dj_site_test\fastmojo\tests\test_account.py", line 46, in test_signup_get
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.085s
```

My test case

```
class SignUpTest(TestCase):

    def test_signup_get(self):
        rechapcha_image = soup.find('img', {'class':'recap'})
        assert rechapcha_image != None
        assert rechapcha_image['src'] != None

        img_url = rechapcha_image['src']
        print ">>>img_url: %s" % img_url
        assert img_url != ""
        assert img_url != None

        response = c.get(img_url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: @Wtower it points to a [`BeautifulSoup` instance](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the full URL in your get request instead of the relative path?

It looks like `c.get(img_url)` should be passed `http://localhost/static/recaptcha/47.jpg` instead of `/static/recaptcha/47.jpg`.

Comment: Tried this, and it's still giving me a the same problem.

Comment: Check that you didn't copy and paste from my original post, I had localost instead of localhost. And maybe try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?